# Load App To Blackberry Emulator From Command line

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

How can I load an application and replace the existing copy to the Blackberry emulator from the command line (not Eclipse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy your app's .cod file into the simulator home directory.  When the simulator is launched your app will appear in the sim.  I prefer this technique because it's simple and easily scripted.  (I developed an automated BB test framework).  Some of the newer simulator's (fledge) have CLI options for loading apps.

Answer (score 3):

Go into your simulator window menu and select "Simulate->USB Cable Connected" and then you can use javaloader as if it was an actual device connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

KeyPress(FRONT_CONVENIENCE). This worked on a 9630 simulator. There's a list of possible key names in the /controller-help for fledge, I just iterated through them and made a guess

edit: This is in response to Vishal